# React js- Element type is invalid:

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, render

**this is my SecExercise**

```js
import React from "react";
import {Text,FlateList,StyleSheet} from "react-native";
const SecExercise=()=>{
    const login=[{user:"admin",pwd:1234},
    {user:"ece",pwd:2023},
    {user:"eee",pwd:3232},
    {user:"non-teach",pwd:222},
    {user:"cse",pwd:1234},
    {user:"mech",pwd:4234},
    {user:"cvil",pwd:2234},
    {user:"bio",pwd:1214},
    {user:"hr",pwd:1274}]

    return(
        <FlateList
            keyExtractor={signin=>{signin.user}}
            data={login}
             renderItem={({item})=>{
                return <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
                    username:{item.user}
                    password:{item.pwd}
                    </Text>;
                 }}/>

    );

};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    textStyle: {
      fontSize: 30,
      backgroundColor:'#fedede'
      
    }
  });
export default SecExercise;
```

** this is my App.js file **

```js
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
import ComponentsScreen from './src/screens/ComponentsScreen';
import FirstExercise from "./src/screens/FirstExercise";
import ListScreen from "./src/screens/ListScreen";
import SecExercise from "./src/screens/SecExercise";
import ButtonAction from "./src/screens/ButtonAction";

const navigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Component:ComponentsScreen,
    First:FirstExercise,
    List:ListScreen,
    Second:SecExercise,
    ButtonsDemo:ButtonAction


  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'ButtonsDemo',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      title: 'App',
    },
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

**after start npm it will show this type error**
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

**same kind of program before I did but there is no error on that time**

**sample code without error**

```js
import React from "react";
import {Text,FlatList} from "react-native";
const ListScreen=()=>{
    const nameAge=[
        {id:1,name:"keerthana",age:23},
        {id:2,name:"Rusanthiys",age:23},
        {id:3,name:"paranthaman",age:25},
        {id:4,name:"priyadrshini",age:21},
        {id:5,name:"saranya",age:30},

]
    return(
        <FlatList
        //horizontal
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} // if u want to hide scrollbar
       // keyExtractor={person=>{person.id}}
       keyExtractor={person=>{person.name}}
        data={nameAge}
        renderItem={({item})=>{
            return <Text style={{marginVertical:150}}> {item.name}-Age:{item.age}</Text>;
        }} 
        />


    );

    

};
export default ListScreen;
```

**but I didn't know why I got this type of error in secExercise program**

Answer (score 0):

It might be from the typo. FlateList is incorrect. Use FlatList instead.

Comment: XD This can be written in comments also

Comment: It's literally the answer :) why it should be in comments?

Comment: No problem Germa :)